# Apache log configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, logging

how to disable apache access log for localhost requests? or for specific IP?

Answer (score 4):

Find `<IfModule log_config_module>` inside httpd.conf (under Windows) or other conf file (under Linux) and add

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" dontlog
```

[Logs in apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html) Conditional Logs section

Comment: I am using apache 2 on ubuntu. How can I enable log_config_module?

Comment: mod_log_config should be compiled in. You don't need to activate it separately. Besides that `a2enmod` is the utility of choice to activate Apache httpd modules on Debian or Ubuntu systems.

Comment: +1 for linking the documentation.